# A didactic example of logarithmic measure

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics, lebesgue-measure, analytic-number-theory

I've read that two mathematicians, in the recent past, studied limits as $X$ tends to infinite, like as 
$$\frac{1}{\log X}\sum_{x\leq X:\pi(x)<\int_{2}^x\frac{dt}{\log t}}\frac{1}{x},$$
where $\pi(y)$ is the **prime counting function**.

**I would like see the proof of some cheap statements like this**, for some series of kind $\frac{1}{G(X)}\sum_{x\leq X:s(x)<g(x)}f(x)$, where $s(x)$ is **some step counting function**, and $f(x),g(x)$ **are, for example, real continuos functions**. If it is possible your example to be inspired in (easy) functions from analytic number theory. If it is possible, as you take $G(x)=\log X$ (it is, I would like see a cheap statement but with functions, if it is possible like previous functions and related with analytic number theory).

> **Question.** Can you show an example going from the anaytic number theory (or from your invention), giving details about how you do the computations, of **logarithmic measure** with finite limit $l>0$
>   $$l=\lim_{X\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log X}\sum_{x\leq X:s(x)<g(x)}f(x)?$$ 
>   Specially how count $x\leq X:s(x)<g(x)$, summing over this set, and how compute the asymptotic.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: It seems that the sum has uncountably many non-negative summands, since as soon as inequality with $\pi(x)$ holds at some $x$, it will hold in some neighborhood.

Comment: I understand your comment, too I ask it to me when I've read this notation, I believe that are integers $n=x$, but when I've read this  in a divulgative journal, I ask the same question to me. Very thanks much @Ulysses

Comment: I've did an update typing $f(x)$ insted of $\frac{1}{x}$, but I would like this function $\frac{1}{x}=f(x)$ or other power if it is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A
 $ a subset of $\mathbb{N}
 $. Then we call the [logarithmic density](http://planetmath.org/logarithmicdensity) of $A
 $ the following limit: $$\delta\left(A\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\log\left(n\right)}\sum_{k\leq n,\, k\in A}\frac{1}{k}
 $$ so for the calculation of the limit we have to calculate (or get an estimation) of that sum. There isn't only a way, you have to understand what is the best tool in your situation. Let's consider a simple example. Assume we want know the logarithmic densty of the primes. So in our case we have $$\delta\left(A\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\log\left(n\right)}\sum_{p\leq n}\frac{1}{p}.
 $$ Since by the PNT we know that $\pi\left(n\right)\sim\frac{n}{\log\left(n\right)}
 $ for the estimation of that sum we can use the [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula), and so $$\sum_{p\leq n}\frac{1}{p}=\sum_{p\leq n}1\cdot\frac{1}{p}=\frac{\pi\left(n\right)}{n}+\int_{2}^{n}\frac{\pi\left(t\right)}{t^{2}}dt\sim\frac{1}{\log\left(n\right)}+\int_{2}^{n}\frac{1}{t\log\left(t\right)}dt\sim\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)
 $$ then we have $$\frac{1}{\log\left(n\right)}\sum_{p\leq n}\frac{1}{p}\sim\frac{\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)}{\log\left(n\right)}
 $$ and so the limit is $0$.

Comment: Very thanks much, your say a simple example but for me **is a nice example**. Very thanks much!